# how to add playback listener in better player flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using [betterplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player)
At 1:00 mark of the playback, i want to pause the video and ask a pop-up question like  “Do you like this video?” with two selectable answers: “Yes”, “No”.
How can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really know this package so there might be a better way than mine (and I can't test it either).

first method:
I would have listen from the progress event until it reaches 1:00 or higher (if user skip time):

```
_betterPlayerController.addEventsListener((event){
    print("Better player event: ${event.progress}");
    if (event.progress >= 1:00){
        launchPopUp();
        }
});
```

second method (if you can't access the video's progress):
I would have listened for a play event when the user start the video:

```
_betterPlayerController.addEventsListener((event){
    print("Better player event: ${event.play}");
    startTimer(); //a method that will start a countdown
});
```

And I would have listened for a pause event, if the user hadn't reached the 1:00 and he stopped it:

```
_betterPlayerController.addEventsListener((event){
        print("Better player event: ${event.pause}");
        pauseTimer(); //a method that will pause the same countdown
    });
```

And finally, I will listen for the countdown going to 0 and lauch the pop up.